# Bootstrap 4 Inline Grid or Sass mixin and performance

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

When I first started using Bootstrap I would generally lay out my grid inline using the classes. For whatever reason, in my mind, it was easier to read etc.

Now, I have started using the sass mixins more. For example:

```
body.archive #secondary {
  @include make-col-ready();
  @include make-col(12);
  @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    @include make-col(4);
  }
}
```

In regards to performance, is there a reason to use one way over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a question about customization rather than performance.

If you need to customize bootstrap's grid then using SASS mixins would help customize it to your needs, but if you don't need that then it would be best to use the already predefined grid classes that get inlined.

Comment: I guess my question was a bit too general. Thanks for the response.